# Is there a way to Disconnect the Function from UIS.InputBegan:Connect(...)?

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried everyway to somehwo make this work... It works on the first time you execute it, but if you try to execute it again it just fails. Here is the code:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    KS.Visible = true
    KSIO = true
    wait(.5)
    UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input, gameProcessedEvent)
        if KSIO == true then
            script.Parent.Text = Input.KeyCode.Name
            KS.Visible = false
            KSIO = false
        end
        print(KSIO)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about the question by editing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disconnect the event, then you can do something like this to disconnect the event.

```lua
local conn
function handle(parm1, parm2)
  -- logic goes here
  if somethingistrue then
     conn:Disconnect()
  end
end

conn = UIS.InputBegan:Connect(handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at globals. Globals in lua are variables that can be accessed from another thread.
You might be looking for this.

```
if getgenv().HasRanBefore then return end
if not getgenv().HasRanBefore then getgenv().HasRanBefore = true end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()
    KS.Visible = true
    KSIO = true
    wait(.5)
    UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input, gameProcessedEvent)
        if KSIO == true then
            script.Parent.Text = Input.KeyCode.Name
            KS.Visible = false
            KSIO = false
        end
        print(KSIO)
    end)
end)
```